# How build CRM 2015 Performance Toolkit in VS 2015?

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm trying of building CRM2015 performance toolkit with visual studio 2015 but the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestFramework dll are missing
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Try going to Project>Manage NuGet Packages, search for qualitytools.loadtestframework and Install the package.

Comment: That's work
Thanks